# How to know if the bean has got some values or not

Tags: java

Suppose there is some bean named **employee**:

and has many fields like **first name, last name, emp no, age , addr, designation** etc.

Is there a way by which I can test if none of the fields have been set?.

I mean, I get a reference through which I can get all values one by one and check if all are empty/null. but is there a better way to find if none of the fields have been set in the bean

Comment: I would try to make beans immutable (bean is created and assumed fully configured.  It there after cannot be altered)... There are problems with long term maintainability when you have mutable beans (it tends to result in non-idempotent operations) but I wont get into it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it exactly like you are thinking...
there is no Out of the Box method for that, but you can
create a method that return a `boolean` and this represent the state of the Bean you want to check...

## Example:

```
public boolean isProperlyInitialized(){
     boolean condition1 = age!=0;
     boolean condition2 = ...;

     return condition1 && condition2 &&....;
}
```

and implemented in the code

```
Bean b = new Bean();

if(b.isProperlyInitialized){
    //Do something cool
}
```